# Rendering of PHP include in SHTML file

Tags: php, include, shtml

I am using a include of a php script in my shtml page.

My server is setup fine to detect and render the mixed php. The page renders the script fine in all browsers.

However... when trying to view the page in Google translate, the path of the script appears to confuse things.

In IE there is a 404 error saying it cannot find the script on the server (implying it thinks it should look on the google servers)

In Chrome and Safari it appears to get over that and try my domain to find it, and it does, but then the rendering of the script takes over and it all that is displayed. Only a brief flash of the main page shows.

Any thoughts would be helpful! Thank you

Comment: Maybe try using Firebug or Chrome inspector to see what requests are being made and what they're returning.  Something I don't get: why would it think it is on Google's servers?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are running Apache and that files with `.shtml` ending work right. In the configuration of the web server search for this line:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

And append `.shtml` to the end of it:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .shtml
```

Now restart the daemon.

By doing so you may save your shtml file as `.shtml`, and it will still be rendered by PHP.

That should solve any confusion problems at other sites.